# Hosting .NET 6 Blazor WebAssembly application on Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-cloud-platform, blazor-webassembly

I am interested in setting up hosting of a Blazor WebAssembly web application on google cloud platform.

Is this currently possible today on the cloud platform? What services are capable of hosting the site targeting .NET 6 Framework?

Since the site WASM is static content, I would prefer serverless functions to deliver the content, but realize this may not be supported quite yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some serverless functions I suggest that could be useful for your application:

- [Cloud Function](https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/create-deploy-http-dotnet)
- [Cloud Run](https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/quickstarts/build-and-deploy/deploy-dotnet-service)
- [App Engine Flexible](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/dotnet/runtime)

Links are provided above with sample application that you can try before you can deploy your own application so that you can check where your application would fit your needs.

Let me know if you have questions or clarifications.

Comment: Thank you! I'll dig in and get started, and let you know if I run into any issues

Comment: Hey, this has been awesome. I was able to fully deploy a .NET 7 blazor app as well as a couple of microservice api endpoints. The server side Blazor app serves really snappy and CI/CD was a breeze to setup as well. Thank you so much!

Comment: Glad to hear that @MST! If you find this question helpful, please consider upvoting/accepting this answer so that it would be helpful for other community members with similar questions just like yours.

Comment: @MST I'm trying  to deploy a Blazor Server app to Goo cloud but keep getting this error, did you happen to come across this error too: Step #1: No valid .NET Core runtime version found for the app or it is not a supported app.

Comment: @E-Bat apologies its been a minute since I touched this guy. I don't recognize that error, but it sounds to me like you're missing the .NET Core runtime in your container. Make sure you're initializing it in the start of the dockerfile